# Quickest way to get squad points in COD: Ghosts?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

I'm having a hard time trying out different guns and equipment because I don't have enough squad points.  One trick I tried is unlocking different squad members in order to try different initial loadouts, but the selection is limited.

Is there a good way to get a lot of squad points quickly?

Comment: completely field orders is a good place, you get 1 per completed order

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of to acquire squad points (besides basically just playing) is by taking advantage of the Operations. By completing Operations you can earn extra squad points for each one completed. Depending on your style of play some will be easier and some more difficult, but if you really work at it they can significantly increase how many squad points you have.

Answer (score 1):

Play local play where you set the game up yourself (team members, enemy bots, map choice), this mode allows you to choose from all weapons, attachments, perks, etc.. So try out everything ahead of time, before wasting your squad points!

Answer (score -1):

Operations, field operations, just playing these are the main ways I get most of my squad points. I have around 320 right now.

Answer (score -2):

I think playing Gun Game gives you 4 squad points every game.

Comment: Do you have a source for this reference?

Answer (score -3):

To get more squad points playing squads try using the last perk on the bottom right hand corner with any sub.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade.  This answer may or may not be correct, but given the brevity of the answer, it is considered very low quality for this site.  Please consider adding more information to this post in order to make it more helpful.

Answer (score -3):

Playing squads will earn you a lot more squad points than multiplayer.